# How to turn off adding mobile classes to some elements

Tags: angular, css, angular-material

I use `matTooltip`:

```
<a *ngFor="let card of cards"
   [routerLink]="['./', card.id]"
   routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive">
  <mat-icon class="dot"
            matTooltip="{{card.name}}"
            matTooltipPosition="below"
            [ngClass]="{'active': rla.isActive}">
    dot
  </mat-icon>
</a>
```

And everything looks good:
[image]

But when I had used screen width a less 900px, I got big tooltip:
[image]

I see additional class, I mean `.mat-tooltip-handset`:

```
<div class="mat-tooltip ng-trigger ng-trigger-state mat-tooltip-handset" ng-reflect-klass="mat-tooltip" style="transform-origin: center top 0px; transform: scale(1);">
    Users
</div>
```

I can create custom `.mat-tooltip-handset` and change default style, but I want disable adding this class.
How to turn off adding `.mat-tooltip-handset`?

Comment: I am having the same problem currently. Have you found a solution to this problem and if so, do you remember what it was?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Gaweringo sorry, unfortunately, I stopped working on that project and technology stack. So, i don't have any solution